# Can Azure DevOps pipeline run make targets?

Tags: azure-devops, makefile, azure-pipelines

In our  project we used GitHub actions to run `make` targets for CI pipeline. We had dedicated runners used in Github actions to run `make` targets

Now, we migrated from GitHub actions to Azure DevOps pipeline

Does Azure DevOps pipeline allow/support running make targets?

Comment: We use Bitbucket as repo. We have two branches in each repo. Feature branch and master branch.  Corresponding Azure DevOps Pipeline (yaml) should get triggered for each branch, on `git push`

Comment: The scenarios that you describe are both possible. You should define your build strategy with branches on the pipeline and you can also execute make commands on the agents. You can use either a custom agent or a microsoft hosted. If the second one does not have make installed, you can do that your own and then run your make commands.

Comment: @GeralexGR What are custom agents? Does azure devops pipeline does not supprot Linux agent?

Comment: Custom agent is an installation that you can perform on a vm or server that you administer. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops . Linux from microsoft hosted agent is also supported